# Django - simplejson response

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery autocomplete plugin http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ to provide search suggestions in my web application where I want to send the response in json format.

Django **views.py** for sending the suggestions response:

```
def keywords_suggestions(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
                suggestions = []
                q = request.POST.get('q')
                try:
                        g = KeywordsModel.objects.filter(keyword__startswith=q).order_by('count')
                except KeywordsModel.DoesNotExist:
                        return HttpResponse("")
                else:
                        for i in range(0,len(g)):
                                global suggestions
                                suggestions.append(g[i].keyword)
                                to_json = {
                                        "query": q,
                                        "suggestions": suggestions
                                }
                        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

Django **models.py**:

```
class KeywordsModel(models.Model):
        keyword = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
        count = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.keyword
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#add-keywords").keyup(function() {
    $('#add-keywords').autocomplete({ 
            serviceUrl:'/keywords_suggestions',
            minChars:3, 
            maxHeight:220,
            width:280,
            zIndex: 9999,
            params: { q: $('#add-keywords').val() },
            onSelect: function(value, data){ $('#add-keywords').val(value); },
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error when I type on the **#add-keywords text box**.

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?q=web&query=web
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

**UPDATE**

```
ValueError at /keywords_suggestions/
The view information.views.keywords_suggestions didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

**UPDATE-2**

I'm having doubt in the suggestions variable, maybe global suggestions will have the problem. Am I doing it right?

Could anyone guide me to make it work?

**UPDATE-3**

```
<input type="text" id="add-keywords" name="add-keywords" title="e.g. Web developer, Javascript, Musician, Jazz" />
```

How to get the value of #add-keywords text box in the Django views.py. Does this work `q = request.POST.get('add-keywords')`?

Thanks!

Comment: Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/?q=web&query=web and you should see the error message.

Comment: open firebug -> console -> ctrl F5 -> error in console -> right click and open in new tab to see the error

Comment: Can you paste the code with correct indent?

Comment: Here https://gist.github.com/2894211 Also check the updated question :)

Comment: Put something in place of return HttpResponse(""). The empty quotes are the problem here.

Comment: You should remove the line:`global suggestions`

Comment: Use `request.GET` or `request.POST` depends on the HTTP method of your AJAX action.

Answer (score 1):

the judgement `request.is_ajax()` returns `False`

Comment: Why? Could you be more descriptive?

Comment: maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755899/django-says-is-ajax-is-false-on-a-jquery-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

The condition branches

```
try:
    g = KeywordsModel.objects.filter(keyword__startswith=q).order_by('count')
except KeywordsModel.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse("")
else:
    ...
```

also could fail as `ValueError` if, for example, `request.POST.get('q')` results `None`

Plus, try `'/keywords_suggestions/'`, note the suffix slash, instead of `'/keywords_suggestions'` in the `serviceUrl:'/keywords_suggestions',` line

Comment: Yes, the problem starts here `q = request.POST.get('q')` It is not actually getting the query value. Why is it so? I've done the jQuery code as shown in the documentation.